# Integrate Heroku system errors with Sentry

Tags: heroku, sentry

I am looking to integrate the Heroku router and system errors with Sentry. Logging my application errors with Sentry is great but I am missing app timeouts and crashes which originate outside the application from the Heroku system. There are logging tools that provide all Heroku system logs but I'd rather use sentry as a single tool for all error monitoring and notifications.

As far as I can see this is currently not supported through plain Sentry/Heroku. The only way that I can see to achieve this is to build my own custom log drain that will filter heroku logs and forward what I consider "errors" to Sentry. Am I on the right track or am I missing some part of the ecosystem?

Comment: did you ever make any progress with this?

Comment: Νο... I only received confirmation in the heroku forums (now closed) that indeed what needs to be done is to build a custom log drain service that will forward errors to Sentry.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. We use Papertrail as our standard log-drain, I'm planning on building an integration for them to post alerts through to Sentry. Feels a bit odd having to daisy-chain services but it should work.

Comment: As a point of reference, Papertail open-source their services and integrations which should make adding one a little simpler. https://github.com/papertrail/papertrail-services

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. I vaguely remember attempting to use Papertrail webhooks for this back in the day, but did not succeed.